# What is the meaning of T Z format in whois output?

Tags: date, whois

I've just notice this format when doing `whois` just now.

What is the meaning of `T` and `Z` format in `whois` output?

E.g.

```
user@linux:~$ whois example.com
   Domain Name: EXAMPLE.COM
   Registry Domain ID: 2336799_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.iana.org
   Registrar URL: http://res-dom.iana.org
   Updated Date: 2019-08-14T07:04:41Z
   Creation Date: 1995-08-14T04:00:00Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2020-08-13T04:00:00Z
```

I assume `T07:04:41Z` was updated on `7:04:41`. So this is time right? Hour, minute, second?

What about `T` and `Z`?

Is this UTC time? GMT+0?

Comment: Those letters are related with the date format. T is just a literal to separate the date from the time, and the Z means "zero hour offset" also known as "Zulu time" (UTC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not specific of the whois command. Instead, is related with the Standard [**ISO 8601**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date and time format.

This format is defined by the sensible practical standard, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

The `T` separates the date portion from the time-of-day portion. The `Z` on the end means [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (that is, an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds). The `Z` is [pronounced “Zulu”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones).